DNN quantile regression
I have a PyTorch model, the purpose of which is to predict quantiles over the output given an input. The output in this case is service time (minutes) for machine maintenance. The inputs detail various attributes about a machine and its usage.
The mean and median times are of less interest than the 90% quantile range (5th to 95th percentiles.) These outputs help us effectively schedule maintenance activities without overloading the capacity.
the issue at hand is that this model produces the same percentiles regardless on input on training and test set data. I need it to adapt to non-linearities far more effectively, which is the selling point of neural networks.
This is a pure prediction model. Interpretation of coefficients and causal statements are out of scope; likewise, a Bayesian model could account for variability in the output given the posterior chain. However, I am not considering alternative approaches at this time.
Preamble aside, below is my PyTorch model
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, TensorDataset

import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, TensorDataset

class QuantileNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size=36, hidden_sizes=[20, 10], output_size=5):
        super(QuantilePDWNet, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(input_size, hidden_sizes[0])
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(hidden_sizes[0], hidden_sizes[1])
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(hidden_sizes[1], output_size)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        
        
    def forward(self, x):
        x = x.to(dtype=torch.float)
        x = self.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = self.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return x

And following, the loss function that enables percentiles to be predicted
def loss_function(output, target):
    p05 = output[:, 0]
    p25 = output[:, 1]
    p50 = output[:, 2]
    p75 = output[:, 3]
    p95 = output[:, 4]    
    
    p05_error = target - p05     
    p05_loss = torch.where(p05_error < 0.0, 0.95*(1-p05_error), 0.05*p05_error)
    
    p25_error = target - p25     
    p25_loss = torch.where(p25_error < 0.0, 0.75*(1-p25_error), 0.25*p25_error)
    
    p50_error = target - p50     
    p50_loss = torch.where(p50_error < 0.0, 0.50*(1-p50_error), 0.50*p50_error)    
    
    p75_error = p75 - target     
    p75_loss = torch.where(p75_error < 0.0, 0.75*(1-p75_error), 0.25*p75_error)
    
    p95_error = p95 - target     
    p95_loss = torch.where(p95_error < 0.0, 0.95*(1-p95_error), 0.05*p95_error)            
    
    return torch.mean(p05_loss + p25_loss + p50_loss + p75_loss + p95_loss)

As far as I can tell from literature review, the quantile loss function is implemented correctly. It uses asymmetric penalties where overestimates for lower percentiles are highly penalized and underestimates for high percentiles are highly penalized; the median experiences equal weight regardless of over/under estimation.
For context, I have 36 input features and 2.5M rows.
Is my quantile loss the source of the problem?
Should my DNN simply have more layers and complexity?
